# Rails Form not rendering json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am fairly new to rails, so please bear with me.  I have a very simple form that takes a couple values and sends it to my `EmailController`.  I run very basic logic on it and just want to return the JSON to the view.  It looks like the controller action is properly rendering the data (I can see in the server output), but the view doesn't change at all.

Here is my `home.html.erb`

```
<%= form_with(url: '/api/v1/emails', method: 'post') do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :email do |ev| %>
    <%= ev.label :address %>
    <%= ev.text_field :address %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Verify' %>
<% end %>
```

and `emails_controller.rb` (simplified)

```
class Api::V1::EmailController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    if @email.save
       redirect_to api_v1_email_path(@email.id)
    else
      render json: @email.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

   def show
    if @email
      render 'show'
    else
      render json: @email, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:address, :id)
  end
```

It says it renders the template, but the view doesn't change:

```
 Rendering api/v1/email/show.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered api/v1/email/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 611ms (Views: 593.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

The template is just simple "hello world" plain text

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: So I think you are getting the workflow confused.  You likely need one controller method to show the form, another controller method to process the data and then show it.  Rails does this typically with a `new` and `create` method.  The `new` method shows the form and the `create` method handles catching the submitted data and then redirecting.  So I think you are a method and view too short here.  I would look at any typically generated Rails controller first and understand it before trying to set up your own solution because as the first comment states, nothing changes the view.

Comment: @RockwellRice Thanks for the response, you are right.  I think I'm closer now, but the view still isn't changing.  I updated the question my new code.

Comment: Your `show` method in its current form does not load `@email`, so its value will be `nil`. You need to `@email = Email.find(params[:id])` in the `show` action.

Comment: Ya `@email` isn't set in your show method.  Again, I would really look at a Rails generated controller and understand that first.  You are missing very basic elements of this and are not doing your self any favors.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz  I don't think that's the issue, it is definitely getting into the if statement, I have been checking with a print statement.  The `@email` variable is an instance variable, and thus accessible from the `show` method.  The `email/show.html.erb` template is getting rendered fine (I can see it in server output), the page just isn't reloading.

Comment: when you use the form_with helper by default data-remote is set to true, it means that rails respond to js format, and it doesn't refresh the page. change it to false (local: true) I think it fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to create the form with `local: true` and it resolved the issue.

```
<%= form_with(url: '/api/v1/emails', method: 'post', local: true) do |f| %>
```